# Change button label text dynamically in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages in my ASP.NET Core web application.

I would like to change the button text from code-behind.  Even if i add `runat="server"` in Html markup and I can't access the button in `*.cshtml.cs` file.

Also, I can not use `<asp:button>` in razor pages. Is there any way to do without using the javascript approach?

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

MyPage.cshtml.cs

```
public IActionResult OnGet(Guid id)
{
if(id == Guid.Empty) //Make button create
else // make it update
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the label on the button?

Comment: @Greg: Yes. Based on the query string, it should be either Create or Update.

Comment: You should be able to bind it to a property in you cs code using the @ syntax `<input type="submit" value="@PropertyName" class="btn btn-primary"/>`

Comment: You can use `TempData`, `ViewBag`, and `@`.

Comment: Right! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor Pages in .net core are quite a bit different than classic aspx pages. There are a number of good intro articles out there in this [one from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). Using your question and some sample code from that article this what the page might look like.

The cshtml file might look like:

```
@page
@using RazorPagesIntro.Pages
@model IndexModel2

<h2>Separate page model</h2>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="@Model.Label" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</p>
```

The cshtml.cs page model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;

namespace RazorPagesIntro.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel2 : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty) {
                Label = "Create"; 
            } else {
                Label = "Update";
            }
        }
    }
}
```